# uploading image and displaying

Tags: php, html

I have a script to upload an image and display it. When i choose an image and click upload, it doesn't update the current image, but if i press f5 it will change the current image... thank you very much in advance. im just new in php.

```
<br><br><a href=\"javascript:location.reload(true);\"><input type='submit' name=save value=save onClick='alert(\"Profile Updated!\")'></a><input type='hidden' name='id' value=$id>";
```

Comment: why is your submit button wrapped in an anchor tag?

Comment: that's because of cache! you can send some query string to refresh it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your browser is probably reusing the cached image, the best way to fix this is to add a unique tag at the end of the image url e.g.

in php i would generally have some kind of helper to do this e.g(very basic):

**

```
function image_tag($url,$attrs){
   $id = abs((int)(microtime(true)*1000)) ); //bit overkill
   return '<img src="'.$url.'?'.$id.'" '.$attrs.' />';
}

echo image_tag('some_url.jpeg',' class="my_image_class" ');
```

**

if you are updating the image with javascript try do something like the following:

```
**$('#some_img').attr('src',some_url+'?'+(+new Date()));**
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

can you display image like  ??

if yes then you have to append time() so it will loaded properly for example display image like ">

if you just upload image using AJAX then get back image data and fill in to image object.

Comment: <form method='post' action='profile.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'><label for='file'>Choose Image: </label>


<input type='submit' name='pic' value='Upload Profile Picture'></form>";

Answer (score 0):

Here you use profile.php page for upload image so after that you have to redirect that page or reload.

for example after upload image put code `header('location:index.php?msg=imageuploaded');`